# Amazon SES says that my domain is not yet verified

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I registered my domain in SES and verified it, but when I send an email using my SES account it says the domain is not yet verified. How should I proceed?

Comment: Can you paste where you see "the domain is not yet verified"? It sounds really strange as if you've verified the domain, you should be able to send emails from any email address inside that domain. Also posting the email, where did you verify it along with the email you're trying to send (from email, recipient...) would help detect where the issue is.

Comment: I've encountered this before. When you verify a domain it is only verified in that specific AWS region. So if you change the region you are looking at it will say it is unverified. Perhaps you are looking at the wrong region?

Comment: I'm from Brazil, but chose the East N Virginia region because the South America region will not be available for the SES service. I tried to attach a picture here but I do not have enough reputation to it. The Aws says the domain is verified, but in the following error (Email address is not verified. (Request ID: 2e059a5a-54de-11e5-ae2f-4fca2defe7c7)) when I have to send an email from "test@goedert.odo.br" to "allan.m.carvalho@provider.com" with a subject and mesage. What do you advise me?

Comment: One more thing, I have a server in the same region validated, yet he keeps giving me an error 554 warning that the domain has not been verified. But say for sure that both the email validation as the DKIM were made and approved by AWS ... I feel very frustrated with it all. :S

Answer (score 0):

Domain verification is "Region" aware so if you send an email using domain xxx.com which is verified in Region A but you use Region B for the delivery, Amazon SES will see xxx.com domain is not verified in Region B thus won't allow you to send the email.

Comment: But I am from Brazil, and my region (south america) is not available the SES service. I am using the US East N Virginia area. What do you advise me?

Comment: One more thing, I have a server in the same region validated, yet he keeps giving me an error 554 warning that the domain has not been verified. But say for sure that both the email validation as the DKIM were made and approved by AWS ... I feel very frustrated with it all. :S